# Calculating variance of a claim payment

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, actuarial-science

I am very confused about this problem and would appreciate some enlightening.

Question: Losses, $X,$ under an insurance policy are exponentially distributed with mean $10.$ For each loss, the claim payment $Y$ is equal to the amount of the loss in excess of a deductible $d > 0.$ Calculate $\text{Var}(Y).$

My apparently incorrect reasoning:

$Y = X - d,$ and we have this theorem:
"For any constants $a$ and $b,$ $\text{Var}(aX + b) = a^2\text{Var}(X)$"

So $\text{Var}(Y) = \text{Var}(X - d) = \text{Var}(X) = 100$ since $X$ is an exponential RV. Where is my mistake?

The answer given is:
$100[2e^{−0.1d} − e^{−0.2d}].$

Comment: $Y=X-d$ isn't true, e.g. what happens when $X<d$? What should the correct expression for $Y$ be?

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, the distribution of $Y=\max(X-d,0)$ will have the same $\lambda=\frac 1 {10}.$

The expected probability that the insurance company will have to pay at all (claim larger than deductible) is given by the distribution of the exponential evaluated at $x>d$:

$$\Pr(X>d)= e^{-0.1 d}$$

Therefore $Y=0$ with probability $1-e^{-0.1d},$ and follow an exponential distribution with mean $10$ with probability $e^{-0.1 d}.$

The $E(Y)=0\cdot (1-e^{-0.1d}) + 10 \cdot e^{-0.1d}$

We are going to need the formula $\text{Var}=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2,$ and the latter part after the minus is $100\cdot e^{-0.2d}.$

The $E(Y^2)$ requires some leg work. By LOTUS,

$$\begin{align}
E(Y^2) &= \int_0^\infty y^2 \cdot 0.1 e^{-0.1y}\;dy\\[2ex]
&=\left.y^2 \cdot (-e^{-0.1 y})\right|_{0}^{\infty} - \int_0^{\infty} (-e^{0.1 y}) \cdot 2y \; dy\\[2ex]
&=\frac{2}{0.1}\int_0^{\infty}y\; 0.1e^{0.1 y}  \; dy\\[2ex]
&=\frac{2}{0.1}E(Y) = \frac{2}{0.1}\frac{1}{0.1}=2\cdot 100
\end{align}$$

but before we apply the formula of the variance, we need to go back to the deductible, and the probability that the company actually has to make payments:

$$E(Y^2)=0\cdot (1-e^{-0.1d})+200\cdot e^{-0.1d}.$$

Now we obtained the desired result $100 \left(2 e^{-0.1d}- e^{-0.2d}\right).$